# Counter that starts fast and ends slower

Tags: calculus

I am trying to make a counter in javascript that counts up from 0 to a variable target number. There is also a time delay between each "tick" that gets slower and slower. So the initial count is fast and over time gets slower.

Now, the length of time it takes to get from 0 to the target variable number is also variable.

How do I make sure that the entire count up process only takes the inputted length of time?

So start number: 0 (int)

Target number: variable (int)

Time of last tick: variable (eg 99(int) to 100(int)) (ms)

Time the entire process takes(ms) (eg. 5000)

And the ticks between each increment gets slower. Start millisecond is 0, last millisecond is as inputted

Comment: Is (or should be) the way the delay is increased each step always the same? That is, is (or should be) there a function $f$ which takes the step $i$ or the delay $D_{i-1}$ at step $i-1$ to give you the delay $D_i$ at step $i$? Also, are you asking for that function or for the increment by which you want to count?

Comment: In a way, that is also what I am trying to figure out. The final "tick" should also be a variable.

Comment: If the timer starts at time 0, then "time of last tick" and "time it takes to target number" are the same, right?

Comment: You need to be more specific, your question is currently too vague. Can you control the length of the ticks? Do the ticks get slower in a specific way, or do they just need to be getting somehow slower?

Comment: The ticks get slower, the final tick should be as specified. Sorry about the vagueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to formalize your requirement. The delay between two ticks is a function $d$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$ which maps each integer $i$ to the delay between $i$ and $i+1$. If you let your counter run up to the integer $n$, the total delay is thus $$
  D(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} d(i) = d(0)+d(1)+\ldots+d(n-1)\text{.}
$$

Now say you want to count up to $n$ *and* you want that to take time $t$. You can simply scale the individual delays by $\frac{t}{D(n)}$, because you then get $$
  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{t}{D(n)}d(i) = \frac{t}{D(n)}D(n) = t
$$
for the total time.

So all you have to do is pick a function $d$. Since you want the timer to become progressively slower, you'll of course pick a function with $d(i) < d(i+1)$. There are lots of choices here, but one particularly convenient one is $$
  d(i) = 2^i \text{.}
$$ In that case you get $$
  D(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} d(i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i = 2^n - 1 \text{.}
$$
If you want to reach number $n$ at time $t$, the delay between $i$ and $i+1$ would thus (per the scaling idea above) have to be $$
  \frac{t}{D(n)}d(i) = t\frac{2^i}{2^n-1}\text{.}
$$

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the idea is to e.g. count to 100 over 60 seconds by updating a counter at apparently randomly chosen times.

This is straightforward; when an update is called after $t$ seconds, set the counter to $t/60\times 100$.

If you're just given the delays $D$ each time, and they're reasonably precise, just add $D/60\times 100$ each time.

If I've misunderstood, sorry, let me know.

Comment: My explanation wasn't too good - the time between the increments wasn't random